# Jquery/JS to reference individual cell content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think my scripting is pretty close, but I cannot seem to return anything.

I have two columns in a table, I would like to find a string in one, and then read down the row to find the contents of another.

I've given both of the columns individual class names, here is my script:

```
if ($("td.cellONE:contains('STRING')")) {
        var OutputCell = $(this).parents("tr").find(".cellONEa");
       console.log($(this).text());
       console.log(OutputCell.text());
      }
else {console.log("no");}
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in your code refers to `window` object, you can use `each` method.

```
$(function(){
    $("td.cellONE:contains('STRING')").each(function(){
        var OutputCell = $(this).closest("tr").find(".cellONEa");        
        console.log($(this).text());
        console.log(OutputCell.text());
    });
})
```

Comment: This doesn't actually return anything. You were right, when I use this example, I return the text of the whole window with reference to $(this), but if I simply use what you've posted, I dont return logs at all. <--Disregard.

Answer (score 1):

`$("td.cellONE:contains('STRING')")` doesn't evaluate as false in a test, even if the jQuery set is empty.

You probably want

```
if ($("td.cellONE:contains('STRING')").length) {
```

And there would be no useful `this` in this case.

EDIT : in fact you probably simply need what undefined proposes.

Comment: Maybe this was a bad example...I apologize, but 'STRING' would be made something that isn't a bad naming convention, like so: if ($("td.cellONE:contains('BOB')")) {
to find BOB in the cell